# How large values of list-max-ziplist-entries and list-max-ziplist-value will affect performance

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, redis-cluster

I am planning to store 100M ids in redis format will be below :

Key : Integer of length 10

Value: An array of unique integers from 0 to 9 (eg : [0,1,2])

What I have planned to do is split the key in two parts(5+5) and use hashes but as we know that list-max-ziplist-entries and list-max-ziplist-value has some limitations.

Let's say that i have decided to configure list-max-ziplist-entries to 100000, how this will affect performaance?

Example :
Key : 1234567891 (hashKey : 12345 and SubKey : 67891)
Value : [0,1]

Comment: There is a good article about this case. it uses `lists` - but you may try yours with hash if you want. it is a cpu/memory tradeoff. https://redislabs.com/ebook/part-2-core-concepts/01chapter-9-reducing-memory-use/9-1-short-structures/9-1-3-performance-issues-for-long-ziplists-and-intsets/

Comment: Thank you for the response. yes i went through this article, bit confused are they using list and doing search on list?

Comment: They are benchmarking with different size using expensive command. Different sizes return different time differences - you may need to make your own to find your best performing size.